# How to implement a Template 10 HamburgerMenu in a single page

Tags: uwp, template10, hamburger-menu

I am attempting to use the Template 10 `HamburgerMenu` control within a single page of a UWP application (in conjunction with the `PageHeader` control), instead of the more typical application-wide hamburger menu that is hosted in a shell page.

The documentation doesn't explain specifically how this should be done, simply stating that "the HamburgerMenu is a XAML control and, as such, can be placed in any page of the application".

Assuming that this control works similarly to a `SplitView`, and using the Template10 `HamburgerMenu` demo code as a starting point, I have added the following minimal implementation to a page:

```
<controls:HamburgerMenu x:Name="Menu">
    <controls:HamburgerMenu.PrimaryButtons>
        <controls:HamburgerButtonInfo ButtonType="Command">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <SymbolIcon Width="48" Height="48" Symbol="Home" />
                <TextBlock Margin="12,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Home" />
            </StackPanel>
        </controls:HamburgerButtonInfo>
    </controls:HamburgerMenu.PrimaryButtons>

    <controls:HamburgerMenu.Content>
        <TextBlock>Sample Text</TextBlock>
    </controls:HamburgerMenu.Content>
</controls:HamburgerMenu>
```

This renders the content `TextBlock`, but not the containing menu. I have experimented with all the obvious `HamburgerMenu` properties, including `HamburgerButtonVisibility`, `DisplayMode`, `IsOpen`, `IsFullScreen`, but nothing has made the menu visible.

Can anyone please point me to a sample that includes the `HamburgerMenu` and the `PageHeader` controls together on a single page?

Comment: is there any specific reason why aren't you using the shell based approach?  That being said, I am working on a demo project

Comment: Tim there is no single page implementation for that control its designed around being the container of all things Frame and navigation.

Comment: @Aditya Sharma. My app requires the hamburger menu on a single page, but not on any of the other pages, as I don't want users to be able to navigate (except backwards) from those pages.

Comment: @mvermef Are you sure about that? The Template 10 documentation specifically says I can do this, but it doesn't explain how.

Comment: @TimCoulter do you want me to provide you with a sample solution that does exactly the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, it was understood that, you don't have an issue with the `shell` based approach of the hamburger template. All you want to do is,

> Show the Hamburger menu only at one page and at the others simply go without the hamburger menu to avoid user direct navigation.

So coming to the solution, the `Hamburger Control` in `Template10` comes with a property `IsFullScreen`. Set it to true like:

```
Shell.Instance.HamburgerMenu.IsFullScreen="true";
```

and this will hide your hamburger menu.

There are two ways you can go about it. I'll first put the solution that can be done but I won't recommend it.

1. You can access the `Shell.xaml.cs` from any page (that's the beauty) as it has a static, singleton instance. You can change the `IsFullScreen="false"` property in the `OnNavigatedTo` and `OnNavigatingFrom` override methods of the `Page` where you want to show the menu and in the shell, keep it as default true. or vis-ver default is set to true, and you can set it to false when navigating out and navigating into the page.
2. The second way (**Recommended**) would be to access the `settingsService` (another amazing feature) which the `Template10` app uses. The `settingsService` is responsible for the the `AppTheme`, the `HamburgerMenu IsFullScreen state`, `using the shell back button or the page header one` along with `Cache duration` and `Hiding the HamburgerMenu` button.

---

**The Reason:** The reason why I would use the singleton instance of the settings service instead of that of the Shell, is because I would want all my app settings to go to an intermediate who would then perform the operations. So tomorrow if I plan to change some functionality based on the values, I'll have to simply edit the settingsService and not search the entire app as to where all do I update this property.

---

**How you do it?**

To follow the second approach and keeping default as false, I would first start off with:

1. File->New project->Hamburger Template.
2. Clean and Build the project (just to get all packages restored).
3. (Optional if you want the default as hidden Hamburger) Go to `Shell.xaml` and add the property `IsFullScreen="True"` to the code line `<Controls:HamburgerMenu x:Name="MyHamburgerMenu">`
4. Now I would go to the page where in I want to show the Hamburger menu (assume it's `detailsPage`), So I go to `detailsPage` and in the code-behind I override the `OnNavigatingFrom` and `OnNavigateTo` methods as below:

   ```
   protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
   {
       Services.SettingsServices.SettingsService.Instance.IsFullScreen = true;
       base.OnNavigatingFrom(e);
   }

   protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
   {
       Services.SettingsServices.SettingsService.Instance.IsFullScreen = false;
       base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
   }
   ```
5. This would do the job. Please Note: I am using the second approach. You can pick the first approach as well.

> Please Note: `IsFullScreen="true"` would hide the `HamburgerMenu` and `IsFullScreen="false"` would show the HamburgerMenu.

[The control's documentation](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/wiki/Controls#hamburgermenu)

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to document that solution in such detail. It works perfectly and I now better understand the thinking behind the design of the Shell and the HamburgerMenu, which means that I will be able to use it in a more flexible way.

Comment: No problem on that. We're all here to help. Exactly! Template10 is awesome and highly flexible